# How do I remove letters and dashes and dollar signs in a string using a regular expression?

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to find all letters and dashes and dollar signs and remove them from a text box.

```
function numbersOnly()
{
    if ($('.sumit').val().indexOf([A-Za-z-$])) {
        $('.sumit').val().replace([A-Za-z-$], "");
    }
}
```

That's what I've got and I'm pretty sure it's wrong. I'm not too great with regular expressions, but I'm trying to learn them. Does anyone want to help me out and get me started with completing this function?

So.. You've got the inputs.

```
<div class="numInputRight"><input type="text" class="sumit" name="sumAmount1"></div>
<div class="numInputRight"><input type="text" class="sumit" name="sumAmount2"></div>
<div class="numInputRight"><input type="text" class="sumit" name="sumAmount3"></div>
```

Then you've got the function:

```
numbersOnly = function()
{
  $('.sumit').val().replace(/[A-Za-z$-]/g, "");
  alert($('.sumit').val());
  return false;
}
```

I'm alerting to determine if the replace is working. It's not.

Comment: None of these work to be honest. I'll update you of what I've got. 

I'm also trying to do this with 3 input boxes.

Comment: You should change the selector from .subit to input.sumit - MUCH better performance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Mark's does it for all non-digits.  If you want to only take out letters, dashes and $, (but leaving decimals, for example), this modification to your original should do it:

```
$('.sumit').val().replace(/[A-Za-z$-]/g, "");
```

(And I personally prefer Mark's updated answer for the same reason he does; you catch everything you can't predict that way.)

For your updated question, the reason the values aren't changing is because val() returns a new string.  It will not change the actual value.  To do that, try:

```
$('.sumit').each(function() { 
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[A-Za-z$-]/g, "")); 
});
alert($('.sumit').val());
```

I also made it into an each() call so that every element would be done individually.

Comment: This worked! I still want to be able to see an alert for each individual input box though. I'm only returning an alert for the first input box. Though.. With the .each(), it should return all the values. Not that big of a deal, I can work with this. Thanks.

Comment: @Michael: Just put this inside the each: alert($(this).val());

Comment: A better regex for this would be

`/[A-Za-z$-.\/\\\[\]=_@!#^<>;"]/g`

Answer (score 149):

This should do it

```
$('.sumit').val().replace(/[^\d.]/g, "");
```

The `[^]` is a negated character class so it's going to match all characters **except** those listed in the character class.

In this case, our character class is `\d` (which is the numbers 0-9) and a period (to allow decimal numbers).

I prefer this approach because it will catch **anything** that's not numeric rather than having to worry about explicitly listing the non-numeric characters I don't want.

If you *really* only want to exclude letters, $, and -, then [Sean's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173612/how-do-i-remove-all-non-numbers-in-a-string-using-a-regular-expression/1173647#1173647) answer is a better way to go.

Comment: If this replacement is being performed often or on long strings, it might be worth adding a `+` after the character group so the pattern doesn't have to perform the replacement once for every character when there is a series of non-number characters. In this case I doubt there will be any noticeable performance gain though, but it's good practice if nothing else. `=)`

Comment: Also, I believe using \D would work. \D being roughly defined as ^\d

Comment: why do you need the `.` here in `[^\d.]`? shouldn't that negate any character? it doesn't, cause it works, but why?

Comment: The . is there to allow numbers with decimal points. So the period in the character class is treated just as a period, not a regex operator.

Comment: @Claudiu in character classes (anything between [ and ]) in most regular expression flavours  only ], \, ^ and - need to be escaped instead of the usual full selection of meta characters: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Answer (score 7):

I really like Mark's answer. However, depending on your programming language (and RegEx engine) `\d` matches characters like ४, or ৮, which are [UTF-8 digits](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm).

So if you only want digits from 0 to 9, use `[^0-9.]`:

```
$('.sumit').val().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
```

This is even faster if your RegEx engine is UTF-8 aware. An example Language, where this applies is python3 (http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html - search for "\d"). The [ECMA Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), however, says that for JavaScript `\d` equals `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('.sumit').val().replace(/\D/g, "");
```

Replaces all non numeric values from sumit value

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
$('.sumit').val().replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
```

I tried Mike's answer with the capital \D instead of negating a \d first which for some reason didn't remove parenthesis and other punctuation for me. Negating \d works perfect.

If you want to keep decimals, maybe put a dot and other symbols within the square brackets too.

PS The environment in which I tested was Titanium SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function numbersOnly()
{
    $('.sumit').val().replace(/[\w-$]/g, "");
}
```

Comment: Actually, \w is [a-ZA-Z0-9_] in javascript, so you might not want to use that.