# BigCommerce Cart Count

Tags: cart, bigcommerce

Wondering if there's a way to pull just the item quantity number in Big Commerce to be displayed elsewhere. I'm using a bootstrap badge image to show the cart count but can't figure out how to get the number only to populate.

This is how it appears now:

[image]

This is how I want it to look:

[image]

Code for cart/badge setup:

```
     <li class="CartLink">
          <span><a href="../cart.php" title="ViewCart"><i class="icon-large sprite-glyphicons_halflings_115_shopping-cart2x icon-2x" style="position: absolute; top: 16px; right: 485px;"></i><span class="badge badge-info" style="position: absolute; top: 20px; margin-left: -60px;">0</span></span></a>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is how Bigcommerce outputs the number of items. However, you can just use javascript to hide the parts you don't want.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! Javascript is an excellent idea but I'm just new at it. Would you mind sharing some code? I edited my post above with the HTML. Thank you in advance!

Comment: See guide in my answer below, this will show you how to remove number from a string.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to hide the parts you don't need.
To only show numbers and hide text using JS you can use this guide. [How do I remove letters and dashes and dollar signs in a string using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173612/how-do-i-remove-all-non-numbers-in-a-string-using-a-regular-expression/1173622#1173622)